# Running ps with clauses as AND instead of OR

Tags: linux, ps

I am looking to see if a specific process is running as a specific user. For which I can do this

```
ps --no-headers -C command -o user | grep user
```

Which is pretty neat, it however gets slightly ugly if I then want to print the arguments (which may interfer with the grep for the username!)

```
ps --no-headers -C command -o user,pid,comm | egrep \^user
```

This would get even messer if I didnt want the user as the first or last column.  What would be neater is if I could specify the -C and -U options in PS like this

```
ps --no-headers -C command -U user -o pid
```

This however doesnt work as the two clauses act as ORs rather than ANDs.  Is there some function of 'ps' that I'm missing, or maybe another neat one liner I could use? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgrep` supports various conditions:

```
pgrep -x -u "user" "command"
```

Replace `-x` with `-f` to also match the arguments; add `-l` to display command line.

You can also read the command line directly from `/proc/PID/cmdline` (null-separated):

```
if pids=$(pgrep -x -u "user" "command"); then
    for pid in $pids; do
        tr "\0" " " < /proc/$pid/cmdline; echo
    done
fi
```